# Avoiding String round-trip in Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have the following code (which is supposed to parse a very trivial `{ "url": "http://some.url.here/" }` hash):

```
import           Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString       as B
import           Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack)


import           Data.Aeson            ()
import           Data.Aeson.Types



newtype SetNextUrl = SetNextUrl B.ByteString

instance FromJSON SetNextUrl where 
    parseJSON (Object v) = SetNextUrl <$>
        (pack <$> v .: "url" )
```

Now notice that I'm hinting that "url" is of type String by using `pack`... This of course will cause some conversion overhead: from the input ByteString to a [Char] and back....

Question: How can I ask Aeson to interpret the "url" field as a ByteString?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aeson` uses `Text` internally for string values, so if you use `Data.Text.Encoding.encodeUtf8` you won't have the `Text -> String -> ByteString` conversion, it'll just go straight from `Text -> ByteString` (which iirc is fairly cheap)

Comment: Thanks! I probably should have used Text in more places and ByteString in less.... But your solution is great!

Comment: @dsign You should use whichever is more appropriate for your application.  If you're manipulating actual bytes, then use ByteString, that's its job.  It's essentially a `Vector Word8` under the hood.  If you're working with ASCII-only data, then it's appropriate.  If you're working with actual human readable/writable text, then use Text.  It handles all the hard parts of encoding for you.  If you want to put ByteStrings in a JSON file, maybe you should be looking at [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) instead.

Comment: @bheklilr That's a very good point and the reason I wrote my comment... I used ByteStrings ala Python 2.x str: for both unicode and bytes.... Some of those uses should rather be Texts.